# Ajax form with model errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created an Ajax form in mvc 4 like that

```
      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updatedDiv", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div id="Errors" class="block">
        </div>

@*<div class="block width-50">
            <div class="input-group" style="direction: ltr">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Incoming No</span>
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="block" id="item-guarantee">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CorrespondenceSideId, 1, new { @checked = "checked" })<label class="label-style">@Global.CorrespondenceSide_Internal</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CorrespondenceSideId, 2)<label class="label-style">@Global.CorrespondenceSide_External</label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CorrespondenceSideId)
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.Label(Global.Correspondence_CorrespondenceNo)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CorrespondenceNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CorrespondenceNo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.Label(Global.Correspondence_IncomingNo)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.IncomingNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IncomingNo)
            </div>

        </div>
}
```

and this is the  controller

```
 public ActionResult Create(Correspondence model)
{
    ViewBag.BoxType = (Enum_BoxType)model.BoxTypeId;

    ViewBag.CorrespondenceTypesList = this.Factory.Get<CorrespondenceTypesService>()
                                                  .GetAsListItems(this.CurrentLanguage);
    ViewBag.AssignmentSidesList = this.Factory.Get<AssignmentSidesService>()
                                              .GetAsListItems(this.CurrentLanguage);
    ViewBag.IncomingSidesList = this.Factory.Get<IncomingSidesService>()
                                            .GetAsListItems(this.CurrentLanguage);

    ViewBag.Lookup_BoxTypes = this.Factory.Get<BoxTypesServices>().GetAsListItems(this.CurrentLanguage, (int)ViewBag.BoxType);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)  return PartialView("_CreatePartial", model); 

    this.Factory.Get<CorrespondencesService>().AuthorizedAdd(model);

    var AllCorrespondences = this.Factory.Get<CorrespondencesService>().GetAll(correspondence => correspondence.Date, (Enum_BoxType)model.BoxTypeId).ToList();
    return new View("Index", AllCorrespondences.ToPagedList(1, 5));
}
```

Now when I return `PartialView("_CreatePartial", model);` and model returns with model errors, that errors doesn't appear in 'validationsummary()' in the partial

Comment: If I understand correctly model errors from the main view will not automatically flow into the partial view unless you add the model errors like 'ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error encountered on the page.");' in the partial view then the  validationsummary will display it.

Comment: I mean the model errors generated from model validation,
I tried ModelState.AddModelError() and it didn't appear in partial validationsummary

Comment: Where is the model errors generated, at the partial view or the main view (from where you're calling the partial)? As for as I know partialview validationsummary will display model errors generated at the model binding to the partial view.

Comment: the partial loaded in a view, the partial has ajax form that calls "Create" actions 
if partial has model validation error I need it to return them to partial that displays them "it didn't occur"
in case of modelstate is vaild then do some action and return "Index" view "that contains the partial" to refresh everything